# Finding Array Index

Tags: php, arrays

I'm hitting a brick wall with this one-
Here's the codethat I have - it's meant to have a forward and backward button which allows me to step through an array. But for some weird reason it's stuck between just two numbers and refuse to show next index in the array.

```
    //$someArray is an array of ten items.
    $_SESSION['theResult'] = $someArray;

    $prev =  $_SESSION['theResult'] [0]--;
    $next =  $_SESSION['theResult'] [1]++;

    echo "<div id='button_div'>
    <form action='" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "'> <input type='hidden' value='" . $prev. "' name=\"id\" /> <input style='float:left;' class='strong_bttn' type='submit' value='<< Previous'></form>

            <form action='" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "'><input type='hidden' value='" . $next. "' name='id' /><input style='float:right;' class='strong_bttn' type='submit' value='Next >>'></form></div>";
```

What I want is that when I press next, the button moves to the next index in the array and if prev is pressed, it moves backward.But its just stuck on 1 and 0.

I don't know if this code makes any sense to anyone. I'm just frustrated and tired that I just want to give up :(

Comment: Why are there so many different indent lengths?

Comment: this is somewhat hard to read :(

Comment: `$prev` and `$next` are just indices, right? Why are you setting them to the value of an array that is indexed by their values?

Comment: Helen, please take some time to describe your problem as if you were describing it to someone who barely knows programming basics. Right now it's really difficult to make sense of *what exactly you are trying to do*, so it's not easy to help you. You 've been working on this for some time and it's obvious to you how "a forward and backward button which allows me to step through an array" works, but it's not as obvious to everyone else. Just spell it out in plain english and you 'll get help much faster.

Comment: I'm with jon here. Maybe start with one value only, so it's more clear what your problem is, e.g. `$prev`. What does `var_dump($_SESSION['theResult']);` show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to iterate through the results array? If yes maybe this can help:

```
<?PHP 
//  is an array of ten items. 
$_SESSION['theResult'] = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g');
$max = count($_SESSION['theResult']);

if(isset($_GET['prevBttn']))
{
    $prev=($next=$_GET['previous'])-1; 
    if($next==0 ) 
        $prev=0;
    echo $_SESSION['theResult'][$next];
}
elseif(isset($_GET['nextBttn']))
{ 
    $next=($prev=$_GET['next'])+1; 
    if($next ==$max ) 
        $next=$prev;
    echo $_SESSION['theResult'][$next];
}
else{ 
    (int)$prev=$next=key($_SESSION['theResult']);
    echo array_shift($_SESSION['theResult']);
 }  
?>   
<div id='button_div'>
    <form action="<?PHP echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>"> 
        <input type='hidden' value="<?PHP echo $prev;?>" name="previous"/> 
        <input type='hidden' value="<?PHP echo $next;?>" name='next' />
        <input style='float:left;' name="prevBttn" class='strong_bttn' type='submit' value='<< Previous'>
        <input style='float:right;' name="nextBttn" class='strong_bttn' type='submit' value='Next >>'>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. It does exactly 100% what I wanted...I could not believe you spent time writing that code. You are a god-send. Stay blessed :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in:

```
action='" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "'
```

It both send to current page, which is why you will only get 2 value. I assume, on page start, it will only show first page and link to second page.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you changing values when determining $prev and $next in the following code:

```
$prev =  $_SESSION['theResult'] [0]--;
$next =  $_SESSION['theResult'] [1]++;
```

You should just base the values of $prev and $next on the value used for the current page, something like this:

```
$prev =  $currentPageId - 1;
$next =  $currentPageId + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the issue, but when you are using ++ or -- after the variable, the assignment happens first, then the variable is incremented. Assign, then increment. So what you are essentially doing is this:

```
$prev =  $_SESSION['theResult'] [0];
$_SESSION['theResult'] [0]--;
$next =  $_SESSION['theResult'] [1];
$_SESSION['theResult'] [1]++;
```

If you want to store the incremented number to the $prev/$next variables, put the ++ -- before the variable.

```
$prev =  --$_SESSION['theResult'] [0];
$next =  ++$_SESSION['theResult'] [1];
```